# Which is the tool used in the image to insert such a table?

Tags: c#

I want help with the tool used to insert such a table

[image: I want help with the tool used to insert such a table]

Comment: You need to be more specific, that looks like the DataGridView

Answer (score 1):

List view or DataGrid Controls in WPF